# How to return a variable in an ajax response?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using a script to upload images to a server. It uses ajax to post the image to a php script where after validation the image is given a unique file name before saving it to a directory. I'm trying to understand how to get the new file name of the image back to my form page as a variable where I can then use that new variable, for example echo it in `<?php echo "new_file_name"?>`. Any help would be really appreciated.

my_form_page.php

```
<div id="preview"><img src="no-image.jpg" /></div>
<form id="form" action="ajaxupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input id="uploadImage" type="file" accept="image/*" name="image" />
        <input id="button" type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
    <div id="err"></div>

<h2>The new file name is: <?php echo "new_file_name"?></h2>
```

The jquery

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#form").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajaxupload.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            beforeSend : function()
            {
                //$("#preview").fadeOut();
                $("#err").fadeOut();
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data=='invalid')
                {
                    // invalid file format.
                    $("#err").html("Invalid File !").fadeIn();
                }
                else
                {
                    // view uploaded file.
                    $("#preview").html(data).fadeIn();
                                        $("#file_name").html(data).fadeIn();
                    $("#form")[0].reset();  
                }
            },
            error: function(e) 
            {
                $("#err").html(e).fadeIn();
            }           
       });
    }));
});
```

ajaxupoad.php

```
<?php

$valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp'); // valid extensions
$path = 'uploads/'; // upload directory

if(isset($_FILES['image']))
{
    $img = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];


    // get uploaded file's extension
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    // can upload same image using rand function
    $final_image = rand(1000,1000000).$img;

    // check's valid format
    if(in_array($ext, $valid_extensions)) 
    {                   
        $path = $path.strtolower($final_image); 

        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path)) 
        {
            echo "<img src='$path' />";


        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo 'invalid';
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: The script works just fine, it returns the picture just uploaded. I just don't know how to go about returning the $final_image variable back to the original form. Looking at firebug console I can see the response is "<img src='uploads/993063tree.jpg' />" if I upload an image called tree.jpg

Comment: If that is the response you can parse it with JS to get the bit you want, but you wouldn't use a PHP echo. You would just assign the image to a selected item and the image should appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the file name back to the script, simply echo it out in php! I would use JSON as a wrapper for your response, so that you can send back multiple values at once, like this :)

```
$response = array(
    'status' => 'success',
    'name'   => $img,
    'path'   => $path
);

echo(json_encode($response));
exit();
```

Next, add "dataType" to your ajax request, like so

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "ajaxupload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        dataType: 'json', <-- THIS RIGHT HERE
```

Now the servers response will automatically be parsed as JSON, so you can access your response like so

```
   success: function(data)
        {
            if(data['status']=='invalid')
            {
                // invalid file format.
                $("#err").html("Invalid File !").fadeIn();
            }
            else
            {
                var name = data['name'];
                // view uploaded file.
                $("#preview").html('<img src="' + data['path'] + '">').fadeIn();
                                    $("#file_name").html(data).fadeIn();
                $("#form")[0].reset();  
            }
        },
```

Just make sure that ANYTIME you echo in your php script, you json_encode the response FIRST, then EXIT!! Otherwise, the script will keep executing and you'll get multiple responses and everyone get's confused.

PS: In ajaxupoad.php, don't forget to change

```
else{
   echo invalid;
}
```

to

```
else{
    echo(json_encode(array(
        'status' => 'invalid'
    )));
    exit(); <-- Seriously, that really is important...
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's brilliant. Works great. Thanks very much.

Comment: anytime :) And remember, always exit() after you echo(json_encode(array))); ! :)

Answer (score 1):

from php script just echo $path and in ajax response use

```
$("#preview").find("img").attr("src", data);

Hope this may help you
```